# Making an oximeter with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, oximeter

Since it is holidays in my place, I started working on a [project that I have seen in Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/Simple-DIY-Pulse-Sensor/); with the help of my Arduino Mega I am displaying the output signal.

These are the results using a red LED in order to recover the oxygen values:

[image]

The circuit I am using:

[image]

The capacitor I found in my house is 620nF so not 500nF as in the schematic.

The experiment was done in the dark; I had no light except the one coming from the red LED.

I am not really sure what I have done and why I am not getting a proper signal.

The code in Arduino contains 1 line :

```
Serial.println(analogRead(A0)*5/1023.0);
```

Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: The circuit you linked to has 2 opamps, yours has one, why did you eliminate an opamp?

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange. The circuit you created does not match that in the tutorial. It is missing the transconductance amplifier.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I thought since the first is just converting the current to voltage, i can use just a resistor to do so.

Comment: C2 is much too small - it needs to be 220uF or so.

Comment: Just to clarify, this will not be an oximeter even if you get it to work. To determine blood oxygen levels you need to look at two different wavelengths. You will instead have a photoplethysmograph.

Comment: You don't specify what photodiode you are using. That would help in determining exactly why your idea of using a current sensing resistor isn't working. In general, transimpedance amplifiers are the preferred method of sensing the current in a photodiode. However, I can't crunch the numbers for you without knowing the specs of your diode.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. i tried the 220uF capacitor but no good signal. I am using a SFH203 photodiode.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes i agree ! i am trying first to figure out how to get a proper signal then i will go to the next step. I believe i have to do it in the Arduino code ?

Comment: No, you need to compare the light absorption of the blood at two different wavelengths, infrared and visible red. You need two LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

I got some results after playing with the circuit. Thanks for the help
[image]